# Starting process in Visual Studio 2017 on Mac

Tags: c#, bash, macos, visual-studio, appium

I'm writing Nunit tests on mac. I need to start a process(server) when tests are being executed. The problem is that test will not finish until server process will not exit. Basicly test runner is stuck and I need to restart Visual Studio. Server process is starting inside of visual studio but I want it to be in a terminal. I need this process to be active even after tests are finished.

```
appProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                appProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "AppiumServer/node_modules/appium/appium";
                appProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--port " + port;
                appProcess.Start();
```

Appium is a bash script with node AppiumServer/main.js. I was trying to start it without bash but when I set fileName to Terminal and Arguments to "node AppiuumServer/main.js --port "+port, node server would start but on wrong port. Can you help me?

appium bash

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
  *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../appium/build/lib/main.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
 node  "$basedir/../appium/build/lib/main.js" "$@"
 ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. Write osascript to launch appium in a terminal and start it from visual studio. Then you can pass port using arguments and access it in bash $0 $1 etc... Server launched like this will start outside of Visual Studio and will not block NUnity tests and terminal launched with osascript will close automaticly.

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script 
"'$1'/AppiumServer/node_modules/appium/appium --port '$2''"'
```

Where $1 is path and $2 port. "appium" is a bash script with node "path to main.js"

And in c# start it like this:

```
Process appProcess = new Process();
appProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
appProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "path to osascript";
appProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "path to appium script this will be in 
$1"+" 8000";
appProcess.Start();
```

8000 is port of course that will be in $2. Hope it will help someone having similar problem.